# How can i add our own field in Ubercart billing address?

Tags: ubercart, entities

I have used Ubercart in my project.
I would like to add my own one field in Ubercart Address field.

How can I?

Does any one had same experience?

Answer (score 1):

Entire order is an object, so having some extra fields for order object from checkout level will solve this.

[Extra Fields Checkout Pane](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_extra_fields_pane) module will help to add additional fields.